# R, shifting parts of rows up

Tags: r

How do I shift the data under ChangeJanAug from row 21 up, in order that the NA are filled with the correct numbers? Since I do not want to shift all the rows, I have to clue what to do.

```
             city latitude JanTemp AprTemp AugTemp ChangeJanAug
1         MiamiFL       26      67      75      83           NA
2       HoustonTX       30      50      68      82           NA
3        MobileAL       31      50      68      82           NA
4        DallasTX       33      43      66      85           NA
5       PhoenixAZ       33      54      70      92           NA
6    LosAngelesCA       34      58      63      75           NA
7       MemphisTN       35      40      63      81           NA
8       NorfolkVA       37      39      57      77           NA
9  SanFranciscoCA       38      49      56      64           NA
10    BaltimoreMD       39      32      53      76           NA
11   KansasCityMO       39      28      55      76           NA
12   WashingtonDC       39      31      53      74           NA
13   PittsburghPA       40      25      50      71           NA
14    ClevelandOH       41      25      48      70           NA
15      NewYorkNY       41      32      53      76           NA
16       BostonMA       42      29      48      72           NA
17     SyracuseNY       43      22      46      68           NA
18  MinneapolisMN       45      12      46      71           NA
19     PortlandOR       46      40      51      69           NA
20       DuluthMN       47       7      39      64           NA
21           <NA>       NA      NA      NA      NA           16
22           <NA>       NA      NA      NA      NA           32
23           <NA>       NA      NA      NA      NA           32
24           <NA>       NA      NA      NA      NA           42
25           <NA>       NA      NA      NA      NA           38
26           <NA>       NA      NA      NA      NA           17
27           <NA>       NA      NA      NA      NA           41
28           <NA>       NA      NA      NA      NA           38
29           <NA>       NA      NA      NA      NA           15
30           <NA>       NA      NA      NA      NA           44
31           <NA>       NA      NA      NA      NA           48
32           <NA>       NA      NA      NA      NA           43
33           <NA>       NA      NA      NA      NA           46
34           <NA>       NA      NA      NA      NA           45
35           <NA>       NA      NA      NA      NA           44
36           <NA>       NA      NA      NA      NA           43
37           <NA>       NA      NA      NA      NA           46
38           <NA>       NA      NA      NA      NA           59
39           <NA>       NA      NA      NA      NA           29
40           <NA>       NA      NA      NA      NA           57
```

Thank you so much!

Comment: How did your get your data to look like this? I'm sorry, but shifting rows if your issue is that of a wrong assignment is the wrong way to go. Is your problem solved by `your_df$ChangeJanAug <- with(your_df, AugTemp-JanTemp)`?

Comment: I used the following commands to get the data to look like this

ChangeJanAug<-temperature$AugTemp-temperature$JanTemp
dfJanAug<-data.frame(ChangeJanAug)
Tempchange<-rbind.fill(temperature,dfJanAug)

Comment: Should have used `cbind`.

Comment: Even cbind is unneccessary, you could just assign a new column with the code I showed in my first problem. Does that solve your issue? Rbind.fill by definition creates new rows.

Comment: cbind did indeed worked, Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the comment of @Heroka that it would have been better to avoid such a situation. But now that you have the data in this form, you could use the following line of code to shift up the entries of the column `ChangeJanAug` by 20 rows:

```
df$ChangeJanAug <- c(df$ChangeJanAug[21:nrow(df)],rep(NA,(nrow(df)-20)))
```

Afterwards you could "clean up" the block of `NA` entries with

```
df <- df[1:20,]
```

If you plan to remove the `NA`s like this, you may not need to bother about vector recycling and you could use simply

```
df$ChangeJanAug <- df$ChangeJanAug[21:nrow(df)]
```

in the first step.

Answer (score 1):

This could be an option

```
data$ChangeJanAug_new = c(data$ChangeJanAug[-(seq(20))], rep(NA, 20))
out = data[colnames(data) != "ChangeJanAug"]

#later if you want to remove NAs you could do this
out[!is.na(out$ChangeJanAug_new),]
```

Using `na.omit` and `cbind` you could do this *(Given you original data is exactly as you mentioned in the question)*

```
cbind(na.omit(data[,-6]), ChangeJanAug = na.omit(data$ChangeJanAug))

#             city latitude JanTemp AprTemp AugTemp ChangeJanAug
#1         MiamiFL       26      67      75      83           16
#2       HoustonTX       30      50      68      82           32
#3        MobileAL       31      50      68      82           32
#4        DallasTX       33      43      66      85           42
#5       PhoenixAZ       33      54      70      92           38
#6    LosAngelesCA       34      58      63      75           17
#7       MemphisTN       35      40      63      81           41
#8       NorfolkVA       37      39      57      77           38
#9  SanFranciscoCA       38      49      56      64           15
#10    BaltimoreMD       39      32      53      76           44
#11   KansasCityMO       39      28      55      76           48
#12   WashingtonDC       39      31      53      74           43
#13   PittsburghPA       40      25      50      71           46
#14    ClevelandOH       41      25      48      70           45
#15      NewYorkNY       41      32      53      76           44
#16       BostonMA       42      29      48      72           43
#17     SyracuseNY       43      22      46      68           46
#18  MinneapolisMN       45      12      46      71           59
#19     PortlandOR       46      40      51      69           29
#20       DuluthMN       47       7      39      64           57
```

Comment: Be careful using `na.omit()` for this.  If you have even one NA in the upper rows, that line will be removed and the result will probably be incorrect.

Comment: @RichardScriven thanks you are right, I did not think of that case, as the sample data doesn't have it.